# Findind more than one word in a file and then extracting the values present after those words?

Tags: c++, string

**Note:** I asked a similar question but that was put "on hold" because i didn't provide my code (i guess). Now i have written my code also but i am facing some other problem.

From my `.bench` file, i have to read the values written in brakects `()` which i managed to do. But the problem is that i have read the values in brakets after `INPUT`, `OUTPUT`, `NAND`.

**`.bench file`**

```
INPUT(1)
INPUT(2)
INPUT(3)
INPUT(6)
INPUT(7)

OUTPUT(22)
OUTPUT(23)

10 = NAND(1, 3)
11 = NAND(3, 6)
16 = NAND(2, 11)
19 = NAND(11, 7)
22 = NAND(10, 16)
23 = NAND(16, 19)
```

So far, i have written the code to find the values inside brackets after `INPUT`, `OUTPUT`, and `NAND` but as it can be seen that i am repeating the similar lines of code again ana again. **So, how can i generalize the same code to find vales after `OUTPUT`, `NAND` etc.**

```
int Circuit::readBenchFile(string filename) //read the benchfile and generate inputs, outputs and gates accordingly
{
    //Reading the .bench file
    ifstream input_file;
    char * S = new char[filename.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(S,filename.c_str());

    input_file.open(S);
    if(input_file.fail())
    {
        cout << "Failed to open Bench file.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    ///////
string line;
string guard_str("#");
string input_str ("INPUT"), output_str ("OUTPUT"), nand_str("NAND");

while (getline( input_file, line ))  
{
    std::size_t guard_found = line.find(guard_str);
    if (guard_found ==std::string::npos)
    {
        ///Input
        std::size_t found = line.find(input_str);
        if (found!=std::string::npos)
        {
            found = line.find_first_of('(', found + 1);
            //Getting our input name and printing it.
            string out = line.substr( found + 1, ( line.find_first_of(')', found) - found - 1) );
            std::cout << out << std::endl;
        }

        ///Output
        std::size_t found1 = line.find(output_str);
        if (found1!=std::string::npos)
        {
            found1 = line.find_first_of('(', found1 + 1);
            //Getting our input name and printing it.
            string out = line.substr( found1 + 1, ( line.find_first_of(')', found1) - found1 - 1) );
            std::cout << out << std::endl;
        }       

        ///NAND
        std::size_t found_2 = line.find(nand_str);
        if (found_2!=std::string::npos)
        {
            found_2 = line.find_first_of('(', found_2 + 1);
            //find first input
            string first_input = line.substr( found_2 + 1, ( line.find_first_of(',', found_2) - found_2 - 1) );
            //Second input
            found_2 = line.find_first_of(',', found_2 + 2);
            string second_input = line.substr( found_2 + 1, ( line.find_first_of(')', found_2) - found_2 - 1) );

            cout<<"\nInputs to NAND gate are:  "<<( first_input + string(" & ") + second_input );

        }           
    }
}           


}
```

Comment: Don't "guess". Read the wealth of material you were linked to by the hold reason text.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, i read...but i can't read the mind of other people so wrote "i guess" :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to do it is to use regular expressions. Good option is the Boost Regex library to do that: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html.

If you are not familiar with regular expressions, here is the great page that will get you started very quickly: http://www.regular-expressions.info/. The first paragraph on the main page will give you the idea.

In short: regular expressions make it possible to quickly find patterns in text. You can quickly build a regular expression and the function depending on it, that would return true if any of the words you are looking for is found.

Comment: I really doubt the best way to do this is with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are looking for genericity I would suggest using boost::split.

```
vector<string> result;
vector<string> value2;
vector<string> nand_case;
boost::split(result , myline, boost::is_any_of("("));
boost::split(value2, result[1], boost::is_any_of(")"));
if (result[0].find("NAND") != string::pos)
  boost::split(nand_case, value2[0], boost::is_any_of(",");
```

will give you for INPUT(23):

```
result[0] : INPUT
result[1] : 23)
value2[0] : 23
```

will give you for OUTPUT(18):

```
result[0] : OUTPUT
result[1] : 18)
value2[0] : 18
```

will give you for 23 = NAND(16, 19):

```
result[0] : 23 = NAND
result[1] : 16, 19)
value2[0] : 16, 19
nand_case[0] : 16
nand_case[1] : 19
```

Hope I understood correctly and this can help.